# How to Combine Multiple Objects by id

Tags: javascript, object

I have a dataset which uses the same `_id` for two different objects and repeats this in the entire file. How do I go through the list of objects, find the two objects that have a matching `_id` and merge them into one object?

```
[    
   {
      "_id": "591323037ca83d48eac1ff31",
      "sessionStartTime": "2017-05-09T23:10:40.000Z",
      "sessionEndTime": "2017-05-10T07:28:40.000Z",
      "timeSessionMinutes": 212,
    },
    {
      "_id": "591323037ca83d48eac1ff31",
      "eventSummary": "Working",
      "eventActivity": "Work",
      "eventStart": "2017-05-09T10:00:00+02:00",
      "eventEnd": "2017-05-09T17:00:00+02:00"
    },
    {
      "_id": "5917165b3ffac25462193490",
      "sessionStartTime": "2017-05-12T22:06:09.000Z",
      "sessionEndTime": "2017-05-13T06:12:09.000Z",
      "timeSessionMinutes": 322,
    },
    {
      "_id": "5917165b3ffac25462193490",
      "eventSummary": "Traveling back home",
      "eventActivity": "Travel",
      "eventStart": "2017-05-09T17:00:00+02:00",
      "eventEnd": "2017-05-09T17:30:00+02:00"
    },
    ...
]
```

Sorry if already answered, could not find a solution for this specific use case.

Comment: See also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42206177/how-to-merge-two-json-object-values-by-id-with-plain-javascript-es6

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An alternative is using the function `reduce` to group the objects by `_id` and the function `Object.values` to extract the grouped objects.

```js
let arr = [   {      "_id": "591323037ca83d48eac1ff31",      "sessionStartTime": "2017-05-09T23:10:40.000Z",      "sessionEndTime": "2017-05-10T07:28:40.000Z",      "timeSessionMinutes": 212,    },    {      "_id": "591323037ca83d48eac1ff31",      "eventSummary": "Working",      "eventActivity": "Work",      "eventStart": "2017-05-09T10:00:00+02:00",      "eventEnd": "2017-05-09T17:00:00+02:00"    },    {      "_id": "5917165b3ffac25462193490",      "sessionStartTime": "2017-05-12T22:06:09.000Z",      "sessionEndTime": "2017-05-13T06:12:09.000Z",      "timeSessionMinutes": 322,    },    {      "_id": "5917165b3ffac25462193490",      "eventSummary": "Traveling back home",      "eventActivity": "Travel",      "eventStart": "2017-05-09T17:00:00+02:00",      "eventEnd": "2017-05-09T17:30:00+02:00"    }],
    result = Object.values(arr.reduce((a, c) => {
      Object.assign((a[c['_id']] || (a[c['_id']] = Object.create(null))), c);
      return a;
    }, Object.create(null)));

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Thanks, works perfectly!

Comment: @Samsoedien you're welcome! `(:`