# Combine 2 JSON objects of unequal size with ID

Tags: javascript, json, netsuite

**Problem**

I would like to have the below two JSON combined together using the ID and have the expected result as mentioned below. I have tried a few solutions that were available but none worked for my use case. Any suggestions will be great !!

*Tried to do:*
[How to merge two json object values by id with plain Javascript (ES6)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42206177/how-to-merge-two-json-object-values-by-id-with-plain-javascript-es6/42206266)

**Code**

```
var json1 = [
   {
      "id":"A123",
      "cost":"5020.67",
      "fruitName":"grapes"
   },
   {
      "id":"A456",
      "cost":"341.30",
      "fruitName":"apple"
   },
   {
      "id":"A789",
      "cost":"3423.04",
      "fruitName":"banana"
   }
];
var json2 = [
   {
      "id":"A123",
      "quantity":"7"
   },
   {
      "id":"A789",
      "quantity":"10"
   },
   {
      "id":"ABCD",
      "quantity":"22"
   }
];
```

**Below is the code I tried:**

```
var finalResult = [...[json1, json2].reduce((m, a) => (a.forEach(o => m.has(o.id) && Object.assign(m.get(o.id), o) || m.set(o.id, o)), m), new Map).values()];
```

**Expected result:**

```
[
   {
      "id":"A123",
      "cost":"5020.67",
      "fruitName":"grapes",
      "quantity":"7"
   },
   {
      "id":"A456",
      "cost":"341.30",
      "fruitName":"apple"
   },
   {
      "id":"A789",
      "cost":"3423.04",
      "fruitName":"banana",
      "quantity":"10"
   },
   {
      "id":"ABCD",
      "quantity":"22"
   }
]
```

Comment: @Taplar I just added the code, that indicated what I tried to do. But it doesn't bring out the desired results.

Comment: That's entirely fine.  It is helpful for us to see where your thought process is, so we can try to identify any issues/errors, and point them out.  So you learn from it.

Comment: @Taplar I understand and I definitely appreciate it!

Comment: Are you sure it's not working?  It appears to be working as is when I tried it in jsfiddle.  https://jsfiddle.net/fm4wg6hq/

Comment: Yeah, this logic works.  So I'm not sure what the issue is.

Comment: Your solution does work.

Comment: That's very strange! It was the cache problem as it wasn't working before! Thanks for pointing out guys !!

Comment: Remember to self answer and accept the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured that by using reduce I could make it work.

```
var finalResult = [...[json1, json2].reduce((m, a) => (a.forEach(o => m.has(o.id) && Object.assign(m.get(o.id), o) || m.set(o.id, o)), m), new Map).values()];
```

Answer (score 1):

You can accomplish this fairly easily without getting too fancy. Here's the algorithm:

1. Put the items from json1 into an object by id, so that you can look them up quickly.
2. For each item in json2: If it already exists, merge it with the existing item. Else, add it to `objectsById`.
3. Convert `objectsById` back to an array. I've used `Object.values`, but you can also do this easily with a loop.

```
var json1 = [
    {
        "id":"A123",
        "cost":"5020.67",
        "fruitName":"grapes"
    }, {
        "id":"A456",
        "cost":"341.30",
        "fruitName":"apple"
    }, {
        "id":"A789",
        "cost":"3423.04",
        "fruitName":"banana"
    }
];
var json2 = [
    {
        "id":"A123",
        "quantity":"7"
    }, {
        "id":"A789",
        "quantity":"10"
    }
];

const objectsById = {};

// Store json1 objects by id.
for (const obj1 of json1) {
    objectsById[obj1.id] = obj1;
}

for (const obj2 of json2) {
    const id = obj2.id;

    if (objectsById[id]) {
        // Object already exists, need to merge.
        // Using lodash's merge because it works for deep properties, unlike object.assign.
        objectsById[id] = _.merge(objectsById[id], obj2)
    } else {
        // Object doesn't exist in merged, add it.
        objectsById[id] = obj2;
    }
}

// All objects have been merged or added. Convert our map to an array.
const mergedArray = Object.values(objectsById);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think a few steps are being skipped in your reduce function. And it was a little difficult to read because so many steps are being combined in one.

One critical piece that your function does not account for is that when you add 2 numerical strings together, it concats the strings.

```
const stringTotal = "5020.67" + "3423.04" // result will be "5020.673423.04"
```

The following functions should give you the result you are looking for.

```
// calculating the total cost 
// default values handles cases where there is no obj in array 2 with the same id as the obj compared in array1 
const calcualteStringTotal = (value1 = 0, value2 = 0) => {
  const total = parseFloat(value1) + parseFloat(value2)
  return `${total}`
}

const calculateTotalById = (array1, array2) => {
  const result = []

  // looping through initial array
  array1.forEach(outterJSON => {

// placeholder json obj - helpful in case we have multiple json in array2 with the same id
let combinedJSON = outterJSON;

// looping through second array
array2.forEach(innerJSON => {

  // checking ids
  if(innerJSON.id === combinedJSON.id) {

    // calls our helper function to calculate cost
    const updatedCost = calcualteStringTotal(innerJSON.cost, outterJSON.cost)

    // updating other properties 
    combinedJSON = {
      ...outterJSON,
      ...innerJSON,
      cost: updatedCost
    }
  }
})

result.push(combinedJSON)


 })

  return result
}

const combinedResult = calculateTotalById(json1, json2)
```